# Complex sort order using entity framework

Tags: regex, oracle, linq, entity-framework

Please help how can I sort this kind of list. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a list of string

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

lst.Add("2.1");

lst.Add("2.10A");

lst.Add("2.1B");

lst.Add("2.2");

lst.Add("ABC");

lst.Add("ABC1");

lst.Add("1.0");
```

sort order would be:

- decimal numbers will treat like a whole number if the string starts with decimal.
- number first followed by letters

Sample result:

1.0, 2.1, 2.1B, 2.2, 2.10A, ABC, ABC1

P.S. If possible i can order it using Oracle and entity framework will be a better solution.

Comment: I don't understand why you have put 2.2 before 2.10A. You state that it would compare numbers first, then letters. When comparing 2.2 with 2.10 as numbers 2.10 would be first then 2.2. Also, isn't 2.1 the same value as 2.10 so they would be equal and then A would be less than B so 2.10A should be before 2.1B?

Comment: 2.10 will be treated as 210 againsts 220 of 2.2
or we can say treat decimal number as whole number

Comment: weird requirement. @_@

Comment: Does my answer help or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Use the sort() method on the list passing in a comparison function. Then in the comparison function use the regex to extract the initial decimal values removing '.' for comparison. When comparing a number with a string, number is less. Compare number first, if equal, then compare the remaining string component.

Explanation of regexMatchDecimal:

- `?:` non-capturing group.
- `\d+` match one or more digits.
- `[.]` match a literal `.`

The regex in `GetString` will just extract the remaining string component after the decimal if there is one and put the result in the first group `()`.

[...] Removed original code as it is no longer relevant.

**Update**

As per the comment, first the integer part and then the integer and fractional part as a whole number will be compared.

The new version:

```
static public class Program
{        
    static string regexMatchDecimal = @"(?:^\d+$)|^(?:\d+[.]\d+)";
    static string GetString( string input )
    {
        string result = "";
        Match match = Regex.Match( input, regexMatchDecimal + @"(.+)" );
        if( match.Success && match.Groups.Count > 1 )
        {
            result = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        return result;
    }
    static bool GetIntValue(string input, out int result)
    {
        result = 0;
        bool isConverted = false;
        Match match = Regex.Match( input, regexMatchDecimal );
        if( match.Success )
        {
            int pos = match.Value.IndexOf( '.' );
            string resultStr = "";
            if( pos != -1 )
            {
                resultStr = match.Value.Substring( 0, pos );
            }
            else
            {
                resultStr = match.Value;
            }
            isConverted = int.TryParse( resultStr, out result );
        }
        return isConverted;
    }
    static bool GetDecimalWholeValue( string input, out int result )
    {
        result = 0;
        bool isConverted = false;
        Match match = Regex.Match( input, regexMatchDecimal );
        if( match.Success )
        {
            string resultStr = match.Value.Replace( ".", "" );
            isConverted = int.TryParse( resultStr, out result );
        }
        return isConverted;
    }
    static public int Compare( string x, string y )
    {
        int xRes = 0;
        int yRes = 0;
        bool hasXNumber = GetIntValue( x, out xRes );
        bool hasYNumber = GetIntValue( y, out yRes );
        int result = 0;
        if( hasXNumber && hasYNumber )
        {
            result = xRes.CompareTo( yRes );
            if( result == 0 )//if same compare whole number decimal components
            {
                hasXNumber = GetDecimalWholeValue( x, out xRes );
                hasYNumber = GetDecimalWholeValue( y, out yRes );
                result = xRes.CompareTo( yRes );
                if( result == 0 ) //compare as string
                {
                    string xSubStr = GetString( x );
                    string ySubStr = GetString( y );
                    result = xSubStr.CompareTo( ySubStr );
                }
            }
        }
        else if( hasXNumber && !hasYNumber )
        {
            result = - 1;
        }
        else if( !hasXNumber && hasYNumber )
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result = x.CompareTo( y );
        }
        return result;
    }        

    static void Go(List<string> lst)
    {
        lst.Add( "2.1" );
        lst.Add( "2.10A" );
        lst.Add( "2.1B" );
        lst.Add( "D.3" );
        lst.Add( "2.2" );
        lst.Add( "2.1A" );
        lst.Add( "ABC" );
        lst.Add( "2" );
        lst.Add( "ABC1" );
        lst.Add( "0.399C" );
        lst.Add( "1.0" );
        lst.Add( "3" );                        
        lst.Sort( Compare );
        foreach( var val in lst )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
        }
    }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {                              
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        Go(lst);
    }
}
```

Output is now:

```
0.399C
1.0
2
2.1
2.1A
2.1B
2.2
2.10A
3
ABC
ABC1
D.3
```

Comment: why 2 and 3 comes first to the list result?

Comment: @VondRitz - because 2 is less than 3 which is less than 10 (which is 1.0 with the . removed). Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: ah... what i mean is order by first by whole number then by decimal number which will be treated as whole number also not decimal system.
for your sample. the result must be 0.399C, 1.0, 2, 2.1, 2.1A, 2.1B, 2.2, 2.10A, 3, ABC, ABC1, D.3

Comment: @VondRitz. OK, I think that I am with you. See update.

Comment: Thank you. Help is so much appreciated. :yes